SWR Renders Old Data When User Account Is Changed from Cache and Later Displays the Actual Data After Fetch
My SWR code is functioning correctly; however, after logging in with one account, fetching an API, and then logging out and switching to another account, the previous data initially renders. Subsequently, the correct data renders once the fetching process is complete. This inconsistency is quite troublesome. How can I ensure that only the relevant user's data is rendered, and there's no display of another user's data while the API fetch is in progress?

  const {
    data: analyticsData,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = useDataLib<{
    status: number;
    success: any;
  }>(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/dashboard/`);



import useSWR, { BareFetcher, mutate } from 'swr';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { LOGOUT_USER, REFRESH_TOKEN, logOutUser } from '@/app/api/auth-api/routes';
import { ApiResponse } from '@/types';
import { SIGN_IN } from '@/app/utils/constants';


const getToken = (): string | undefined => {
    return Cookies.get('access');
};

export const handleSignOut = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/${LOGOUT_USER}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${getToken()}`,
            },
        });

        await response.json();

        Cookies.remove('access');
        Cookies.remove('refresh');
        localStorage.removeItem('userData');

        window.location.href = SIGN_IN;
        return;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to logout user', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

const handleUnauthorized = async (): Promise<void> => {
    return await handleSignOut();
};

export const fetcher: BareFetcher<any> = async <T>(url: string, fetcherOptions: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<T | Blob> => {
    let token = getToken();
    if (!token) {

        handleSignOut();

        // throw new Error('No token found');
    }

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            ...fetcherOptions,
            headers: {
                ...(fetcherOptions?.headers || {}),
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                // Access token expired or invalid, try refreshing
                const refreshToken = Cookies.get('refresh');

                if (!refreshToken) {
                    // No refresh token available, logout user
                    throw new Error('No refresh token found');
                }

                const refreshResponse = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/${REFRESH_TOKEN}`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ refresh: refreshToken }),
                });

                if (refreshResponse.ok) {
                    const newTokens = await refreshResponse.json();
                    token = newTokens.access;

                    // Update cookies with new tokens
                    Cookies.set('access', token as string);
                    Cookies.set('refresh', newTokens.refresh);

                    // Manually trigger revalidation
                    if (mutate) {
                        mutate(url);
                    }

                    // Retry the original request
                    return await fetcher(url, fetcherOptions);
                } else {
                    // Refresh token is invalid, clear cookies and redirect to login
                    await handleUnauthorized();
                }
            } else if (response.status === 500) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong');
            } else {
                // throw the error as it is
                const errorData = await response.json();

                throw new Error(errorData.error);
            }
        }

        // check if the response is a blob
        const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
        if (contentType && (contentType.startsWith('application/pdf') || contentType.startsWith('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'))) {
            return await response.blob(); // Return the blob directly for file downloads
        }

        return await response.json();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);

        console.error('Failed to fetch data', error);
        throw error;
    }
};


const useDataLib = <T>(swrKey: string, swrOptions: Record<string, unknown> = {}) => {
    const { data, error, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR<T>(swrKey, fetcher, {
        revalidateOnFocus: false,
        errorRetryCount: 3,
        ...swrOptions,
    });

    return { data, error, isLoading, mutate };
};

export default useDataLib;




  const handleSignOut = async () => {
    await logOutUser();

    localStorage.removeItem("userData");
    setUserData(null);

    dispatch(setAccessToken(null));
    dispatch(setRefreshToken(null));

    router.push(SIGN_IN);
  };


